# Problem with filtering data via custom function in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get 4 random objects from `Product` I'm trying to filter it by `check_existing_id` function and `random.randint` and I use `while` loop to get 4 objects from the database. However this piece of code in some cases returns only 3 objects. There is a bug hidden in the code and I have no idea where I need this to return exacly 4 elements every single time. I'm pasting the code below it's just a simple function:

```py
def check_existing_id(list,number):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] == number:
            return False
    return True

class GetRecommendedProducts(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        product_id = self.kwargs['product_id']
        products_length = len(Product.objects.all())
        id_list = []
        while len(id_list) < 4:
            id = random.randint(0, products_length)
            if check_existing_id(id_list, id) and id != product_id:
                id_list.append(id)

        return Product.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```

Comment: What is `product_id = self.kwargs['product_id']` doing here?

Comment: It gets id of a product from the url so It won't be included in id_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`sample(…)`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) of the [**`random`** package [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). You can first fetch the list of primary keys (excluding the `product_id`), then sampling four items, and then fetch the `Product`s:

```
from random import sample

class GetRecommendedProducts(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        id_list = list(Product.objects.exclude(
            id=self.kwargs['product_id']
        ).values_list('id', flat=True))
        return Product.objects.filter(id__in=sample(id_list, 4))
```

Comment: I got this error : Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d)

Comment: @mateuszlaczynski: yes, you should use a `list(...)`, updated.